# arraylist with method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, output

As my last question obviously was a little bit unclear (I applogise for that), I'm making a new try, and this time I will really try to be clear.

Here is the code I have written so far

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Head {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String fname, lname;
    int choice;

    ArrayList<People>list = new ArrayList<>();

    People p1 = new People("Mia", "Wallace", "1111");
    People p2 = new People("Marcellus", "Wallace", "2222");

    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);

    System.out.println("Welcome");

    System.out.println("1) Add person \n2) Last name \n3) Print list");
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        People.walk(); //calling the method
        break;
    case 2:
        People.run();
        break;
    case 3:
        People.crawl();
        break;
    }   
}
}
```

People class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class People {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String fname;
private static String lname;
private static String dob;

public People(String fname, String lname, String dob){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getFname(){
    return fname;
}
public String getLname(){
    return lname;
}
public String getDob(){
    return dob;
}
public static void walk(){
    System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
    fname = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
    lname = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter dob: ");
    dob = scan.next();
    list.add(new People(fname, lname, dob));  **//list cannot be resolved**     
}
public static void run(){
    System.out.println("Remove people");        
}
public static void crawl(){
    int peoplenumber = 0;
    System.out.println("\nNumber of peoples: " + list.size()); **//list cannot     be resolved**
    for(People p : list){ **//list cannot be resolved**
        peoplenumber += 1;
        System.out.println("#" + peoplenumber + "\n" + p.toString());
    }
}
public String toString(){
    return "First name: " + this.fname + "\nLast name: " + this.lname + "\nDateOfBirth: " + this.dob;
}
}
```

I do understand why I get the error, but I don't know how to get around it. Any help?

Am I right when I try to move code from the main-class to the costructors?

If you guys have any comments or ideas how I should solve this, or move on with java, I will gladly here them.

Thank you very much for your time and your help :)

Comment: When you choose "first name", what output do you expect to see?

Comment: I was hoping to get "First name: " and then the user should be able to put in just that

Comment: what is it that you want to do in ``case 1`` and ``case 2``?  Do you want each of the elements in ``person`` to "walk" or "run"?  If so then you need to iterate over ``person`` to make each element do that.

Comment: For which person? One of the people in your list? For a new person that you will add to the list afterwards? Right now you are adding three people to the list and then always printing the first one's name.

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend renaming ``person`` to ``people`` to express its plural nature.

Comment: That's correct. That was just to have some names in my list. I'm aiming to add a new person in the long run. But first out just let the user enter a new name wich can be displayed. My biggest issue here is to get stuff between the classes. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The arraylist should be in the main class. If it were in the person class, it would be created once for every person object you create. To access a method for that person, you want to call the name of the OBJECT (not the type), the .method(parameters).

If you wanted to call run on p1 (not really sure what you want to call it on), you would use:

```
p1.run();
```

That would perform the code in the run method where it is defined.